# running whole lua script from c

Tags: c, binding, lua

I am started to learn Lua few days ago and faced next problem. How can I run the whole lua script form C program, for example, I have a lua script and read it like a text file in my C program so how can I run this script from C side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using [luaL_dofile](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_dofile). even no need to read the text file in separately.

In [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/25.html), they do it using luaL_loadfile (to allow for some more flexibility)

Comment: But now I faced one more problem, how can I create a table in Lua from C-side, and then pass this table to the function

Comment: This is a different question, but I could give you the general hint of reading the pil book I linked in my answer.